# Search in string with Python

Tags: python

I used subprocess.Popen on a program and obtained following output

```
(Class'byte')    b'CPU0_V1.8_AUX    | 1.82 Volts        | ok\r\nCPU1_V1.8_AUX    | 1.82 Volts        | ok\r\nSYS_V12_AUX      | 12.20 Volts       | ok\r\nSYS_V5_AUX       | 5.03 Volts        | ok\r\n'
```

My goal is to be able to search a particular string, for example CPU0_V1.8_AUX and obtain 1.82. what's best way of doing it ? Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Comment: What are we to provide feedback on? You haven't shown us what you tried.

Comment: Please provide a minimum functional code.   We need to be able to reproduce the string.  In what you are showing us, the leading b' suggests that it was reprocessed or formatted.

Comment: I was only asking for the best method of doing a task like this. Not exact function code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Convert to string, parse, then search through string.

```
def search(value, x):
    x = x.split('|')
    for i, l in enumerate(x):
        if value in l.strip():
            return l[i+1]
    return False

x = b'CPU0_V1.8_AUX | 1.82 Volts | ok\r\nCPU1_V1.8_AUX | 1.82 Volts | ok\r\nSYS_V12_AUX | 12.20 Volts | ok\r\nSYS_V5_AUX | 5.03 Volts | ok\r\n'.decode("utf-8") 

result = search('CPU0_V1.8_AUX', x)
print(result)
```